# Cant access single object in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, preact

[image]Hi I am having problems with accessing Object in array... I dont know is it because i updated Chrome or because i added, and after removed Preact from my React application. Problem is this:

Tags is array of objects:

```
var fullTag = tags.filter(tag => tag.tagId==tagId);
console.log(fullTag);
```

And as a result i get this in console:

```
  [{…}]
```

When i expand it i get this:(image)

So there's no way to access it except with

```
console.log(Object(fullTag[0]).tag);
```

In all other ways i get undefined... Why is this?! I can swear that i could access it with fullTag.tag until yesterday... Can someone explain me please?

Comment: Well your image shows that it's an array which is why you can't access its members.

Comment: *I can swear that i could access it with fullTag.tag until yesterday* - unless your code was different yesterday, nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided **callback** function.

So, after you `filter` an `array`, you will obtain another `array` even if there is only one `item` which pass the `test` function. That's why you couldn't access it using `fullTag.tag`.

Solution is to access one element using its `index`.

```js
let tags=[{"id":1,"tag":"tag1"},{"id":2,"tag":"tag2"}];
let tagId=1;
var fullTag = tags.filter(tag => tag.id==tagId);
console.log(fullTag);
console.log(Object(fullTag[0]).tag);
```

If `tagId` property is unique in your array you can use `find` method.

```
var fullTag = tags.find(tag => tag.id==tagId);
```

Now you can access your `tag` property in that way you `wished`.

```
console.log(fullTag.tag);
```

Comment: @Ivan, maybe you used `find` method.

Comment: I suppose that the tagId is unique in your array..so, you can use it like in my answer.